# find . file -/+ size except *.filetype

Tags: ubuntu, find

I am looking for a way to do something that can find all files less than size except filenames with an extension or more. May be more than one.

```
find . -type f -size -20M -name /! -name *.mp3 -delete
```

From some of the things I found online I thought that this would be what I was looking for but it is not working. Pretty much I am looking for this

```
find . -type f -size -/+ size (except) *.ext -delete
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!` is the `find` *not* operator. So to exclude files ending in .ext from the results, include the term `! -name \*.ext`.

For numeric arguments such as file size, a prefix of `+` means *greater than* and a prefix of `-` means *less than*. So to find a file larger than 12 kilobytes (really kibibytes) and smaller than 500 Megabytes (really Mebibytes), include the terms `-size +12k` and `-size -500M`.

Your second example would then look something like this.

```
find . -type f -size +12k -size -500M ! -name \*.ext -delete
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I use it to clean up a folder automatically for me. so if I wanted to not delete multiple extensions would it be

    find . -type f -size +12k -size -500M ! -name \*.ext \*.ext -delete

Comment: A file name with one or more extensions contains at least one dot, so it would match the pattern `*.*`. A file name with two or more extensions contains at least two dots, so it would match the pattern `*.*.*`. If you want to make sure that each extension contains at least one character, you could replace those patterns with `*.?*` and `*.?*.?*`, respectively. It really depends on the file names you're dealing with. You want a pattern no more complicated than necessary to distinguish one set of files from the other. And of course test it before using it to delete anything.

Comment: sorry there is a space between those. I was meaning *.ext and *.ext?

Comment: If you want to delete only those files whose extension is *not* `.ext` *and* is *not* `.ext?`, then you could use `find ... ! -name \*.ext ! -name \*.ext\\? -delete`. Note that if that extension really contains a question mark, the question mark will have to be escaped so that it is seen by `find` as a literal question mark and not as the symbol for "any single character".